# android volley simple http request

Tags: android, android-volley

New to volley.
Quick question.
I can get volley simple HTTP request to work fine when placed in onCreate
Is it possible to put the request into a separate class?

Android studio cannot resolve "stringRequest" in this example. Help much appreciated...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Retriever go = new Retriever();
        go.queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

public class Retriever {


    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = "http://www.google.com";

    public StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // mTextView.setText("That didnt work!");
        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: Is `Retriever` an inner class of `MainActivity`? It is hard to tell that with your indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `stringRequest` variable is in the scope of `Retriever` class, its visibility is contained in that class only. That's why you are getting that error.

It will go away if you write

```
go.queue.add(go.stringRequest);
```

as you are referencing the object from the instance of its class.

Comment: yep thats it. Well explained. Cheers.